# How to use values of generator objects?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Nx6 for the dataset, where N is the number of samples.

And when I run this line of code:

```
segments, labels = segment_signal(dataset)
```

It gives the error:

> TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [45.0] of <class 'float'>

The definition of the function segment signal is the following:

```
def segment_signal(data,window_size = 90):
    segments = np.empty((0,window_size,3))
    labels = np.empty((0))
    for (start, end) in windows(data['timestamp'], window_size):
        x = data["x-axis"][start:end]
        y = data["y-axis"][start:end]
        z = data["z-axis"][start:end]
        if(len(dataset['timestamp'][start:end]) == window_size):
            segments = np.vstack([segments,np.dstack([x,y,z])])
            labels = np.append(labels,stats.mode(data["activity"][start:end])[0][0])
    return segments, labels
```

And the helper function:

```
def windows(data, size):
    start = 0
    while start < data.count():
        yield start, start + size
        start += (size / 2)
```

I troubleshooted it and it appears that this line is causing the error:

> x = dataset["x-axis"][start:end]

I analyzed it further and it seems that `windows()` is a generator function. Hence, the `(start, end)` in `segment_signal` are generator objects. But error occurs in the `x = dataset["x-axis"][start:end]` for some reason that I could not understand.

The problem is that I can print the values of `start` and `end`, but I can't use their values. Say, use them as index for the `x`.

Turns iut that `start` and `end` are floats.

I just did `int(start)` and `int(end)`. But when I did `x = dataset["x-axis"][start:end]` and get the shape `x.shape`, the answer is (24,), when it should be 90 (because the window size is 90. But when I computed `end - start` the answer is still 90. And when I printed `x`, it only has 26 elements when it should have been 90. Why is this?

Comment: Post stack traces with code-formatting, not quote-formatting. (This will also fix the problem of stuff in `<>` not showing up.)

Comment: Don't try to unapply quote-formatting and then apply code-formatting, though - the quote formatting already irreversibly mangled the stack trace. You'll need to recopy it from original error output.

Comment: I think this is as simple as you're passing floats into your slice indices, no?  `start += (size / 2)` is changing `start` to a float.  Are you on Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @JAV python 3. I don't get why `dataset["x-axis"][start:end] ` gives an error.  `start` and `end` are just numbers computed from `windows()`

Comment: The problem is that I can print the values of `start` and `end`, but I can't use their values. Say, use them as index for the `x`

Comment: My hunch is that they are floats; they need to be ints.

Comment: @JAV turns out you're correct, I just did `int(start)` and `int(end)`. But when I did `x = dataset["x-axis"][start:end]` and get the shape `x.shape`, the answer is (24,), when it should be 90 (because the window size is 90. But when I computed `end - start` the answer is still 90. And when I printed `x`, it only has 26 elements when it should have been 90. Why is this?

Comment: @JAV you are correct. Please post your answer :)

Comment: Can you post a sample of your dataset?  What is data.shape?

Answer (score 0):

I think JAV is right about the variables' type. Try this simple (not sure if it's the best) solution

```
for (start, end) in windows(data['timestamp'], window_size):
    start = int(start)
    end = int(end)
    print("check start and end",start,end)
```

I hope this helps